# How can I run a specific program on a large number of files in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

There is a program called gmadconv.exe which takes one parameter, the name of the file you want to convert without quotations. I have attempted to use a FORFILES loop to pass the name of each file to gmadconv.exe, but it automatically inserts quotes, stopping gmadconv from actually working. How do I cut out the quotation marks and pass the result to gmadconv? Also, I'm totally new to shell scripting, and my only programming experience is in Java.

The code I am using to extract the GMA files is:

```
FORFILES /c "gmadconv.exe @file" /m *.gma
```

Also, I do have access to the .c file the program uses.

Comment: odd... quotes a pretty much required for filenames, since filenames can contain spaces and quotes are the only way to make those spaces be considered part of the filename.

Comment: All the files I'm converting don't have spaces in their filenames.

Comment: Post the command you are using. You can always use the output of `DIR` inside of a `FOR` loop.

Comment: I'm using this: FORFILES /c "gmadconv.exe @file" /m *.gma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely have to avoid the quotes, you can do this:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %A IN (`DIR *.gma /B`) DO gmadconv.exe %A
```

Note that this is a one-liner from the command prompt. No batch file is needed.

If you need to run the command in a batch file, it would be:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A IN (`DIR *.gma /B`) DO gmadconv.exe %%A
```

Comment: @jediKatana - Forgot you are running in a batch file. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, saved my server's life.